# Simplify Check for Unique flag on IndexAttributes

Tags: c#, .net, linq, attributes, refactoring

The following LINQ statement does something seemingly simple, but has ended up becoming fairly complex. Is there a simpler way to accomplish the same task, and what process would one go through to break this down?

```
public static bool ArePropertiesUnique(Type type, params string[] propNames)
{
    return type.GetProperties()
        .SelectMany(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IndexAttribute), true)
            .OfType<IndexAttribute>()
            .Where(i => i.IsUnique))
        .GroupBy(g => g.Name)
            .Where(a => a.Count() == propNames.Count())
        .SelectMany(g => g)
            .Select(i => i.Name)
        .Intersect(propNames
            .Select(prop => type.GetProperty(prop)
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IndexAttribute), true)
                .OfType<IndexAttribute>()
                .Where(i => i.IsUnique)
            .Select(i => i.Name))
        .Aggregate((list, list1) => list.Intersect(list1))).Any();
}
```

**Summary**

This piece of code looks for index attributes on an entire class, compares them to the property names passed in, and sees if those properties contain a set of indexes that force the property name combination passed in to be unique.

Comment: I'd *start* by putting each operation on a separate line. That in itself will make it easier to read.

Comment: First of all it's even not possible to say what this piece of code is doing, beucase it's too long and too complex. If you are the one who understands the logic, split the parts of it into subqueries, and then do filtering & intersecting in the memory between results of the subqueries. That's the general strategy to approach the problem.